# Localization of apk strings in both english UK and english US?

Tags: android, localization, google-play, apk, android-resources

I'm new to android. So, It may be asking a silly question. I have added description in both English US and UK in Play Store. Now it's asking me to upload apk. Can I upload the same apk used for UK and US as there's no difference in strings. Do I need to add new folders inside the values directory even if there's no difference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

define string.xml for both language, one in values folder and make another string.xml in the folder named values-en-rGB.

Comment: UK stands for Ukrain. The correct value path is values-en-rGB

Comment: I defined `strings.xml` in `values` , `values-fr`, and `values-en-rGB` (for English UK). In code I set `Locale(en-us)` / `Locale(en-gb)` / `Locale(fr)`. All of them work except **en-gb**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AlaaM. I had a similar issue. When you have two files with the same languages you need to set the country too or it will fall back to the deafult one.

Comment: The recommended standard is to use `values-b+en+001` for World English, and default is US English. US English is considered not part of the world, and I assume this is a bodge, as 001 covers all countries, including USA. This is even true for Unicode; the km-unit is called "kilometers" in `en` and "kilometres" in `en_001`, and `en_US` is not included.

Answer (score 3):

You only need one APK for all languages. You do not need to upload one for each language.

Adding separate strings.xml files is fully optional, and it does not have to match the languages and variations you've entered on Google Play.

Answer (score 2):

No, as long as your `strings.xml` file is located under the basic `values` folder.

Comment: I read on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html
 It says "you could create a small file called res/values-en-rGB/strings.xml that includes only the strings that should be different when the application runs in the U.K. For all the rest of the strings, the application will fall back to the defaults and use what is defined in res/values/strings.xml."
Since I have no strings to be changed, because they are exactly similar. So I'm not creating a new folder "values-en-rGB". Am I doing Okay? If so, I should upload same apk in both translations on play store?